# Wpf, C# - Contextmenu in TabItem Header

Tags: wpf, header, contextmenu, tabcontrol, tabitem

I wanted to add a contextmenu to a tabitem. But it should only be opened by clicking on the header of the tab

```
if (!(View.tabContent.Items[View.tabContent.SelectedIndex] is TabItem tabItem))
            return;

        ContextMenu ctm = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem m1 = new MenuItem();
        m1.Header = "a";
        m1.Click += M1_Click;

        MenuItem m2 = new MenuItem();
        m2.Header = "b";
        m2.Click += M2_Click;

        ctm.Items.Add(m1);
        ctm.Items.Add(m2);

        TabControl tbc = View.tabContent;

        tbc.ContextMenu = ctm;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace each TabItem's `Header` with a ContentControl that wraps the actual content for that header while also replacing the ContextMenu:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <ContentControl Content="FirstTab">
            <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Foo" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Baz" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
        </ContentControl>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Grid Background="CornflowerBlue" />
</TabItem>
```

Obviously this can also be done entirely in code-behind, and if you only need the menus to  be dynamic then you can just declare an empty ContextMenu like so:

```
<ContentControl Content="FirstTab">
    <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="FirstMenu" />
    </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
</ContentControl>
```

...and then populate that in code-behind:

```
FirstMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Foo" });
FirstMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Bar" });
FirstMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = "Baz" });
```